# Keep javascript within new javascript element

Tags: javascript, styles, nicedit

I am developing a webpage but I came into some trouble with some javascript code.

I am using the [Nicedit](http://nicedit.com/) as WYSIWYG for textareas, which, as stated in its main page, is as easy as copy/paste this 2 lines anywhere in my web page:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

That's working great with the default textareas of the page. The problem is that I also have this javascript to add more textareas:

```
function addchapter()
  {
  if (num_chapter < 10)
    {
    var num=num_chapter+1;
    document.getElementById('chapters').innerHTML += "<h3>Chapter " + num + "</h3> Title: <input type='text' name='titlechapter_" + num + "'><br>Content:<textarea  name='chapter_" + num + "'></textarea>";
    }
  else if (num_chapter == 10)
    {
    document.getElementById('chapters').innerHTML += "<br />Maximum is 10 chapters.";
    }
  num_chapter += 1;
  }
```

So when I add a textarea through javascript, it doesn't have the proper style; it's not implementing Nicedit. The thing is that the textareas are all standard, so there's no difference between the code in both cases. I don't know too much of javascript but I think that the problem might be that the Nicedit code runs ONCE when the page loads, and that's it. **Any idea of how to make it run when the page loads (<= already done) AND when the `addchapter` function is run?**

The relevant HTML bit is this:

```
 <div id="chapters">
 </div>
 <button type="button" onclick="addchapter()"> Add chapter </button>
```

My page where you can see the odd behaviour is <strike>**this**</strike> (broken link), under Chapter 1 you see the 'Add chapter' button.

Thank you all so much.

EDIT 1, Error console output:
When the page loads it throws this:

```
"GET http://js.nicedit.com/nicEditIcons-latest.gif 
bkClass.extend.getStylenicEdit-latest.js:8
bkClass.extend.constructnicEdit-latest.js:38
AnicEdit-latest.js:8
bkClass.extend.addInstancenicEdit-latest.js:37
bkClass.extend.panelInstancenicEdit-latest.js:37
nicEditors.allTextAreasnicEdit-latest.js:37
bkLib.domLoaded"
```

When I add a new chapter:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<bkClass> has no method 'removeInstance'
bkClass.extend.checkReplacenicEdit-latest.js:37
bkClass.extend.panelInstancenicEdit-latest.js:37
nicEditors.allTextAreasnicEdit-latest.js:37
(anonymous function)/file/new/:112
onclick"
```

Comment: I think you know your problem, likely you have to call `nicEditors` and pass each newly created textarea element as you create them, or perhaps you can just keep calling `nicEditors.allTextAreas` and it will know which ones it's already been added to. The documentation should tell you that.

Comment: How did you getrid of this error?

Comment: I ditched Nicedit altogether and went with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which is more complete and has a ton of pluggins which you can install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign a unique ID to the text fields you add to the page. To convert it into an editor you can then call;

```
nicEditors.findEditor(editorID);
```

Or you can call `nicEditors.allTextAreas()` again. But I'm not sure if that will remove the existing content from the editors that already exist.

Source: [The API](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API).

Comment: I tried both `<button type="button" onclick="addchapter();nicEditors.findEditor('nnicedit');"> Add chapter </button>` (assigning to the new element `id='nnicedit'`) and `<button type="button" onclick="addchapter();nicEditors.allTextAreas();"> Add chapter </button>`. Neither of them worked...

Comment: I have been looking for that but couldn't find out how to get that. How do I check the errors? Through extensions? I'm using Chrome for Ubuntu, any recommendations?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos  Press F12. Error notification will be bottom right.

Comment: I answer this in the main window as it's too long

Answer (score 0):

You can add try{}catch(e){} block to your code

```
jQuery('.js-control-des').each(function () {
            var index = jQuery(this).attr('lang');
            var editor = jQuery(this).find('textarea');
            var editor_id = editor.attr('id');
            var editor_loaded = editor.attr('rel');
            if (editor_loaded == undefined || editor_loaded != null || editor_loaded == 0) {
                var editor_new_width = parseFloat(editor.css('min-width')) + 7 + 'px';
                editor.css({
                    width: editor_new_width,
                    'max-width': editor_new_width,
                    'min-width': editor_new_width
                });
                try {
                    new nicEditor({maxHeight: 300}).panelInstance(editor_id);
                    jQuery(this).attr('rel', 'editor-loaded');
                    jQuery(this).find('.nicEdit-main').attr('data-index', index).keyup(function (e) {
                        if (vnLineUcp.editorKeyUp(jQuery(this)) == false) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                }
            }
        });
```